# How to update variable array names inside "for" loop and store its value for later use in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to automate the assignment of data arrays to new names,
The folder contains multiple files of arbitrary names, each file contains two columns of data
here is the code to open those files:

```
import numpy as np
import os

d = {}
x = {}
y = {}
myfiles = [myfile for myfile in os.listdir() if myfile.endswith(".txt")]
print(myfiles)
ran = len(myfiles)
for myfile in myfiles:
    d[myfile] = np.loadtxt(myfile, delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
    for i in range(ran):
        x[i], y[i] = d[myfile]
        #stuff I didn't figure out
print(x1,y1)
print(x2,y2)
.
.
print(xn,yn)
```

the task is to store say x1 y1, to use them outside the loop. the naming scheme must also be kept x1,x2,x3...etc
The code so far saves only the last two arrays xn, yn

Comment: No, don’t do that. Any time you are tempted by variable names organized into a scheme like `x1, x2...xn`, you should be using a list `x` and appending your data. Then access it with `x[0], x[1]…x[n]`.

Comment: `x` and `y` are dictionaries, not arrays.